# problem in authenticated rooms in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to create rooms for all private chats between two connected users. I'm not getting the point how do users join the room securely.

```
// client side code
var socket = io.connect();
socket
    .emit('Join-Room',"{\"username\": \"myusername\", \"password\" : \"mypassword\"}");

// server side code
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('Join-Room', function(userdata) {
   connection.auth(userdata,function(success){
     if(success){
       socket.join(username);
     }
   })
  });
});
```

The problem is when the client emits a request even to join a room the credential data is received by everyone in the namespace?

What should I change to make this secure?

Comment: you can try to authenticate the user when on connection event is fired.

Comment: Already authenticating users on-connection event, using socketio-auth package, 
but the problem is still there, think this way you are logged in connected to your room chatting with someone, if someone else wants to read your chats it can be easily done but sending a request to the server of joining that specific room and server will accept it.

Comment: you can have a list of allowed users for a particular room, stored in memory, every time some user tries to connect he must provide room name when he wants to join, each time user emits data to some room you can validate some token.